# How to add an attribute to the body tag with a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, html

Is there any way to add an attribute to the `body` tag?

For example:

```
<body test-attribute>
```

Obviously this can be easily edited in the theme, but I'm trying to figure out how to add it with a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you can (easily) add arbitrary attributes to the `<body>` tag.

However, WordPress provides the function [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) so you can add classes to the `<body>` tag.

If your theme uses it, you'll find something along these lines in a template file (eg. `header.php`):

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

In that case, you'll be able to filter the array of classes being passed using the `body_class` filter:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse388651_body_class' );
function wpse388651_body_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'my-custom-class';
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very, unconventional, way of doing it.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'my_func');
function my_func ($classes) {
    echo 'data-custom="Hello World!"';

    return $classes;
}
```

Filters should always return the value and never echo (output) the value.

This works because of the `body_class()` position, the `body_class()` echos the class tag, part of the echoed value is a function that contains the `body_class` filter.

Using that filter we can output or own values before the `class="..."` is outputed.

That is the basic idea, you can edit it to fit what ever you need.